# Selectively enable MathJax

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

One of the reasons against enabling MathJax network-wide is the slower page load time. That's true, but can't we detect whether MathJax was used and only enable it in that specific post ?

The posts models are loaded anyway (possibly from cache) each time a question page is rendered, so why not just add a boolean field to the models to tell whether Mathjax was used, and if any of the models have the field set then include the Mathjax library when building the page. That shouldn't cause any performance issues for the whole site (as it will only be loaded if any of the requested posts have the boolean set), and I don't think anyone would mind the extra overhead of loading Mathjax on a question which really needs it.

When posting/editing a question, the editor could use some basic regular expressions to detect whether Mathjax is in use and set the boolean field when submitting the post, with an optional checkbox to let the user override the automatic detection if it ever fails.

Comment: Related: [MathJax-only code snippets could be simplified into Math Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283127)

Comment: What about question lists? Like the homepage, sidebars (related/linked/hot network questions) and so on? If they have mathjax in the title, the whole page should include mathjax in order to display them correctly. Or should such questions be removed from all lists?

Comment: @Oded  If users understand that title won't be rendered, they won't put MathJax there. On sites like SO it's not really needed in the titles, tricky formulas come up in post bodies. Also, mobile apps don't render MathJax in titles at all, which is apparently acceptable.

Comment: @Oded we should probably ignore that fact and just have a guideline to avoid Mathjax in titles for sites that don't have it enabled on the homepage.

Comment: @pizza - you are assuming people will avoid it in titles. They will not. And if we disallow it on titles but allow it is post bodies, people will complain about _that_.

Comment: @Oded I find it difficult to imagine that anyone who wants their question answered would put raw LaTeX in the title. If they do, some discouragement should dissuade them. The number of questions that actually need LaTeX in the first place is pretty small. Some people will probably complain if you disallow it in titles, but only a very small subset. Another thing that could be done is only allowing $$ math, not inline $ math. This will discourage people from using it too much.